# Use Tkinter After To Get Return Value And Return It Again

Tags: python, function, tkinter, delay, sleep

I needed a delay before calling a function and getting its return value. But  `time.sleep` is freezing the tkinter GUI so i used `tkinter.after`. `tkinter.after` is working and won't freeze the window, but I cannot get the return value of the function that I've called. Because after I delayed and got the returned value, I've to return it again to the other function that called this function.

I've been struggling with this, please if any of you know any solutions, help me

This is the basic example of whats going on

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep


def getvalue():

    value = "haha"

    sleep(3)

    return value


def printvalue():

    value = getvalue()

    print(value)



app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("500x300")

button = tk.Button(app, text="print value", command=printvalue)
button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe I don't understand your problem but can't you use `tkinter.after` in new function `delay()` which will call `printvalue` with delay and then `printvalue()` can run `getvalue()` without delay - or put it directly in `Button` ie.  `command=lambda:app.after(1000, printvalue)`

Comment: but what if the delay has to be in get value, cause there is some other function that need to be run first and than delay it. the button just an example to call the function after the tkinter windows showed up. to make it clear i want the print value to return the value again and the main one will be like this `mainvalue = printvalue()`

Comment: first: if you run it as `command=printvalue` then you can't use `mainvalue  = printvalue()`. You would have to run `command=other_function` and inside `other_function()` run `mainvalue  = printvalue()`. Second: if you can't resolve it with `tkinter.after` then run it all in separated `thread` and it will not block main thread with GUI.

Comment: you can also try to split function in two parts - code which has to be executed before getting value with delay and code which has to be execute after getting value with delay. Then `tkinter.after()` should run function which gets value and runs second part - so it doesn't have to send it back to first part.

Comment: thats exactly the problem, the `tkinter.after()` just delaying the function that we put in, not delaying the code below/after `tkinter.after()` wich in this case `return`

Comment: wich that i think that exists in thread/multiprocessing using `.join()`

Comment: `tkinter.after()` doesn't stop current function but it sends information to `mainloop()` that it has to execute other function later - and this is why all code after `tkinter.after()` would have to be in executed function, not in current function.

Comment: so in this case should i use thread instead?

Comment: I don't know - all depends on what you really have in this code. if it will be easier for you to use thread then use it. But thread may have own problems - ie. thread shouldn't access GUI elements/widgets.

Comment: all i need is a delay. to tell my program to wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple example I would use `tkinter.after()` to run function with delay. And all code afer getting data I would move to second function which is executed by `tkinter.after()`.

But your real code can be more complex and it can be hard to split it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def getvalue():
    return "haha"

def second_part(other):
    print('after delay')

    value = getvalue()

    # code moved from first part
    print('value:', value)
    print('other:', other)
    button['text'] = value

def print_value():
    # first part makes some calculation
    other_variable = 'some value'

    print('before delay')

    # run function with delay and send all data from first part
    app.after(3000, second_part, other_variable)

    # rest of code moved to second_part

app = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(app, text="print value", command=print_value)
button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** If you have problem to use `tkinter.after()` then you can try to use `Thread` to run `print_value` which will have to wait for `getvalue()`.

But `Thread` sometimes may have problem to access GUI widgets in main thread.

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
import threading

def getvalue():
    sleep(3)
    return "haha"

def print_value():
    # first part makes some calculation
    other_variable = 'some value'

    print('before delay')

    value = getvalue()

    print('after delay')

    print('value:', value)
    print('other:', other_variable)
    button['text'] = value


def start_thread():
    t = threading.Thread(target=print_value)
    t.start()

app = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(app, text="print value", command=start_thread)
button.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

---

I was thinking about `asyncio` which has non-blocking `asyncio.sleep()` but `asyncio` needs to run own loop which would block `mainloop()` so it would have to run in `Thread`.

Comment: this gives me an idea, but wont work on my real code, because its object oriented wich means there is a return after return and so on. but this can be use for procedural because we can pass not just a variable but a function as parameter using `tkinter.after()`

Comment: but is it worth it to rebuild all my code just for the `tkinter.after()` ?

Comment: I often see the same problem - if you shows easy example then you can get solution which works for it and it can be easy to use in this simple example but it may not work with real code which is more complex and it may have other problems. As I said before if it will be easier for you to use thread then use thread.

Comment: yep i think i would be better using thread cause i can just make some little changes, or i can make its own class to change the `sleep` or `tkinter.after()` function, and i think i can even use it as a decorators